# Could be possible to transfer the normal of a geometry node primitive?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I'm using the `DataTransfer` modifier to replace the normals of this tree with the normals of a sphere

[image]

I will like to be able to do the same thing in a geometry node by transfering to the geometry the normals of a primitive

[image]

I have a UV Sphere here and I only see the `Normal` node, but I don't see anything like `Set Normal`

Is this thing that I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244428/19156