# How can I set image textures per instances using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to set image textures per instances using geometry nodes.

I could get ids of instances and set colors per instances.

But I don't know how to set image textures.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Crantisz. Thank you for your idea.
I tried it but I couldn't set UVMap correctlly.
But I find the way in an article below.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241507/where-is-a-proper-way-to-get-back-uv-map-after-realize-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a bunch of mix RGB nodes (example with 4 images):

[image]