# How can I transfer instance UV after realising in geometry nodes without applying the modifier?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I need to export an Geo nodes animation as alembic file without loosing the UV maps of the instances to use the animation in Unreal Engine 5?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot export GN nodes...so you have to realize the GN modifier if you want to export it...because GN is (still) a "just used in Blender"-thing

Comment: This is a duplicate actually: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241507/where-is-a-proper-way-to-get-back-uv-map-after-realize-instances