# Geometry Nodes: set sharp or crease attribute for an edge

Tags: geometry-nodes

All pre Blender 3.0 tutorials use *Fill Attribute* node for setting an attribute like sharp. Many attributes are now set in a different way, for example there's a dedicated node to set smooth shading. However, I couldn't find anything for edge sharpness.

Let's say I want to add a geometry nodes setup for the starting cube:

[image]

Which should mark 4 edges of the cube sharp and crease them

[image]

Which would allow me to add *Subdivision Surface* and *Split Edges* modifiers to get a bullet shape:

[image]

I'm actually after something more complex than a bullet shape but still I have no idea how to set named attributes in Blender 3.0...

So what should be inside *Set Sharp* and *Set Crease* custom nodes so the setup works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Crease (Blender 3+)

[image]

Defining the **Crease** output in the modifier stack to be a `crease` attribute sets the crease. However this doesn't work by defining **Sharp** as `sharp` or `sharpness` attribute…

[image]

Also, the `crease` attribute exists at the beginning, which can be seen in the spreadsheet. `sharp` doesn't…

The specific situation described in my question could be solved entirely by geonoodles:

[image]

### Sharp - Blender 4

I'm leaving the old answer for old Blender versions and to present the technique for other properties like this recent question:

[Is setting the freestyle edge parameter via geonodes possible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/311172/60486)

However currently the "Set Shade Smooth" node supports both "Face" and "Edge" mode, allowing you to dynamically set edge sharpness:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Setting Edge sharpness

This post is a third in the series of:

> How do I use an existing modifier to create a bridge between geometry nodes and a property the geonodes setups can't access?

1. [Assign vertex group in Geometry Nodes (v3.3)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275405/60486)
2. [How to apply Geometry Nodes with UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276549/60486)
3. This technique.

This time rather than splitting edges, storing their positions, moving each near a sharp or normal edge, transferring data by positions, restoring positions and merging by distance (where information on split edges would be lost, as it is in the UV technique), I decided to transfer by topology:

1. Take object named `Main`, duplicate it as `Main.stage.2` (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is fine, Mesh data doesn't need to be duplicated) and disable `Main` visibility (at least for renders) as it's just a first stage that's not supposed to be visible anymore.
2. Create a custom group *Sharp Mapping*, which checks runs through provided edges, and for each either creates a plain simple edge, or imports the sharp edge provided as an object wrapper:

[image]

3. Obviously you need to create the abovementioned sharp edge wrapper: just create a new cube primitive, delete all edges but one, select the remaining edge, right click, *Mark Sharp*. Name the object `Sharp Edge`.
4. Add a new geonodes modifier to `Main` object to store the edge sharpness information using the *Sharp Mapping* node. For example, if you want to set all "horizontal" edges sharp:

[image]

[image]

5. Remember to link the `Sharp Edge` object in the geonodes modifier, as well as an attribute name (any available name will work):

[image]

6. Finally, add *Data Transfer* modifier to the `Main.stage.2` object; non-default settings marked yellow:

[image]

[image]

[image]