# Animate Bevel Weight Parameters

Tags: animation, keyframes, bevel

Is there a way to animate the bevel weight settings of a group of lines? Hitting "I" in Edit Mode to insert an animation key doesn't work and I can't find *anything* when searching the web. Any idea is much appreciated

Comment: This could be done in a hacky way, by using geometry nodes + data transfer modifier, similar to this technique: [Geometry Nodes: set sharp or crease attribute for an edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/247851/60486) - however, because bevel weight is not a boolean, you would also need to use a vertex weight of a vertex group, so you would need to connect the technique above with this one: [Assign vertex group in Geometry Nodes (v3.3)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275405/60486)

Comment: Thanks Markus. I was expecting something hacky but I guess this is too complex for my level of skills. Maybe I'll set the values by hand since the animation will not have too many frames