# Vertex Group created within a Geometry Node Object (Blender 3.5)?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

Through geometry nodes I'm trying to create something that functions like a vertex group within a geometry node object in Blender 3.5 and above. Basically, this would be to exclude part of the mesh for a boolean object that functions as a "hole cutter".

I'm thinking that through named attributes, and stored attributes there must be some way of singling out specific geometry to use - much like vertex groups function. The problem is that this is within a geometry node object, so, there is no way to highlight the vertices in edit mode. So far I haven't been able to find anything like this in YouTube tutorials, or looking through other threads on the blender stack exchange.

Comment: Please produce some example of your problem. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274922/60486

Comment: why don't you just use separate geometry and boolean mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your suggestions. I was able to solve the problem by adding the "Store Named Attribute" node between two "Join Geometry" nodes. The node appeared directly after the items I wanted the boolean object to surround, then the other items were connected in the later "Join Geometry" node.
[image: Store Named Attribute between "Join Geometry"]

Then, for the boolean object I used the following setup:
[image: Boolean setup]

This refers to the stored attribute before a "Delete Geometry" node. Anyway, the result is just like using a vertex group with a regularly modeled item!