# How do I bend a square horizontal bar like in the picture?

Tags: modeling, mesh, physics

I want to bend a square bar with a hollow inside.
What should I do to bend it into the shape as shown in the reference pictures?

If possible, I would like to know how the square bar bends in Blender using physics.

I'd like to make a video where the square bars are bent and crushed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are so many ways and approach to this : you can model it by hand, sclupt or even use physics or what not. What have you tried already?

Comment: I've just started blender, and I'm still researching how to do it on the web.

Comment: If possible, I would like to know how the square bar bends on the blender using physics.

Comment: I'd like to make a video where the square bars are bent and crushed

Comment: Maybe this tutorial could lead you to the right direction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzfhjgn1oVw&pp=ygUZYmxlbmRlciBzb2Z0IGJvZHkgcGh5c2ljcw%3D%3D ?

Comment: I will try it after watching the video.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Playing around with a cloth simulation, I managed to get that far:

[image]

Adding subdivisions before the cloth simulation will increase the foldiness, though that also depends on cloth resistances:

[image]

I started with the default cube, resized it on $z$ axis, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> added loopcuts to make it roughly square-quads based again, but then decided to add much more loopcuts in the bending area:

[image]

Probably many of those sparse loopcuts away from bending can be removed, and the dense loopcuts shifted up, as I wrongly predicted where I'll bend…

The bending animation is done using this modifier stack:

[image]

- bevel to add holding loops for Subdivision Surface
- Subdivision Surface to give it the final base profile and geometry density
- Simple Deform to bend by 90°
- The magic of cloth sim
- Smooth the bends so faces don't overlap on themselves
- Another Subdivision Surface to further smooth the output by adding vertices

Proper Weight Painting is crucial, and so by improving it you will get better results than me:

[image]

Cloth settings are extremely important as well, but I left most settings to defaults and just pinned the weights from above and added just a touch of pressure from inside to direct the bends outside:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What a beauty! I wonder whether  a blurred GN-generated tension-map would stand any chance of doing your weight-painting for you.

Comment: @RobinBetts nice idea, I was thinking of something similar: after first pass, convert it to shape keys, then weight-paint the areas based on how much you want them to change. Could even weight-paint individual frames differently using [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275405/60486), then replay simulation, rinse, repeat until happy with the result…