# How to symmetrize weight paint?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I need guidance on how to make the weight the same on both sides, two meshes that are symmetrical to each other and an armature.

[image: Selected finger]

[image: bent finger]

[image: selected finger]

[image: bent finger]

[image: weight paint for the problematic side]

[image: weight paint]

Comment: My formatting is awful but i can try and describe the images. 1-hand i want to copy with a selected finger... 2-hand i want to copy with a bent finger as an example... 3-hand i want to fix/replace with a selected finger... 4- hand i want to fix/replace with a bent finger (it is not the same)... 5- weight paint for the bad hand... 6-weight paint for the good hand... hope this helps

Comment: you could use geonodes plus this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274922/assign-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes-v3-3/275405#275405

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Remove the right hand
- Mirror the left hand with a *Mirror* modifier
- Make sure that the left hand and right hand bones are correctly name (finger1_L, finger1_R, etc)
- Weight paint the left hand
- Apply the modifier, it will automatically mirror the weight paint

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to mirror weights when you're drawing them. "Mirror vertex group" and mirror "X".

Bones need to be named correctly, with "left" and "right" suffixes, as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html).

[image]