# How to add new vertices to a Vertex Group in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image][image]I am creating some new geometry and would like to assign it to the appropriate vertex group, so I can later apply a bevel in modifiers or add material. I've created the VG but am struggling to figure out how to assign verts to the group in GN.

I added a screenshot of the simplest version of what I am trying to do. I want to set the VG on one of these items only to "Steps", then apply the bevel later as a modifier. I don't want to use the existing geometry.

Comment: I think there still isn't a better way in Blender 4.0... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275405/60486

Answer (score 0):

On my end (Blender 4.0) this seems to work. Based on an existing vertex group named "bevel".

[image]

Node Tree

[image]

Though i don't believe this will work if it doesn't have the vertex group already created, e.g. trying to create the mesh and vg whole-cloth from within GN.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but despite the attribute appearing on the proper verts, ALL of the geometry is receiving the bevel, not just the Vertex Group.

Comment: Are you sure you assigned the verts in the VG correctly? If you want only the ones from your GN selection then you should go into edit mode, select all and then click "Remove". Make sure they're not all just default-added to the group.

Comment: I deleted the VG's and started over with just "Steps" VG. I removed all and tried it. Added them back in and tried it. Deleted the original geometry and tried it. It's still all or none. I added another screenshot with the basic node setup. You can. see that half the verts have a Steps of 1.000 assigned.  I also noticed that sometimes to see changes in the Viewport, I have to click off the Geometry Node Modifier and on the Bevel Modifier. That'll update the viewport. Is this expected behavior?