# How to create a vertex group with the intersecting edges of mesh node boolean?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel, boolean-modifier

The store named attribute that I put after my mesh boolean doesn’t find the vertex group that exists on the object. No matter how hard I look, I can’t find why it doesn’t work.

The goal would be to make a bevel but only on intersecting edges.

[image]

And the link to download my project.
https://we.tl/t-k70dWFUqI4

Sorry and thank for your help

Comment: the reason why it doesn't work is, that you are creating the vertex group on your plane, not on the created geometry in GN

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274922/60486