Geometry Nodes - when I Join, my Vertex Groups are deleted

What to do in such a case? When I try to use Join and it deletes Vertex Groups for me

Mesh boolean works... I use it here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274922/assign-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes-v3-3/275405#275405
I think this means you can delete all geometry where you have vertex groups and the boolean then is fast and yet joints the vertex groups - but then I don't know if you can restore the values, probably

An other reference about "why" : get Vertex Group to survive Geometry Nodes. For "how", see Markus comment.
