How do I get geometry instances to inherit vertex groups from found vertex groups
I have a model in blender that has the following geometry modifier heirarchy:
Armature -> GeometryNodes (AssembleStickFrame)
How it works is that I have a wireframe mesh (no faces). The armature deforms the mesh the way I want. And I made a custome geometryNode the replaces the wireframe with spheres at each vertex and cylinders on each edge. It works fine until I move the geometryNode above the armature which I need to do to properly import the model with its wire thickness into godot but the armature no longer deformes because the cylinders and spheres aren't assigned to any vertex group. I have no idea how to get vertex groups from vertexes in geometry nodes nor do I know how to assign geometry to vertex groups in geometry nodes. So I'm stuck with no other alternative.





Maybe this will work? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274922/60486

And since you're exporting this, you could use a python solution to change an attribute into a vertex group before export.

I might just have to export the mesh without the geometry nodes and figure out how to code it into godot.
