# Pack existing UV islands of a specific UV set using geometry nodes?

Tags: modifiers, uv, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Pack UV Islands node but I don't have a good enough understanding of geometry nodes to know how it's supposed to be used and my searches haven't shown many examples.

The reason I want to do this with geo nodes is that I'm masking geometry non-destructively using modifiers and would like to keep the modifiers while repacking the UVs that I have (in my second UV set) procedurally, so that whenever my mask is changed, the UVs change without requiring modifiers to be applied.

[image]
Here's my attempt, which isn't really doing anything helpful at the moment.

Any idea if and how I can accomplish this with geometry nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Store Named Attribute" instead. It's not better, it's just that then it's clearly visible if you:

- set the attribute in the correct domain, which is face corner.
- give the attribute a correct name, which I imagine is `LightMapUV` (to override the old attribute).

In your case you probably set it to a vertex domain instead - which you can see if you press <kbd>N</kbd> inside the node editor area:

[image]

Other than that, perhaps you don't know that the UV Map is originally stored using a *legacy* datablock, and it is converted to an attribute inside your geometry nodes. Unfortunately since Blender is undergoing a migration towards the attributes (hence the term "legacy"), the shaders still read from the old data-block; in order to read from an attribute, use the "Attribute" node in your shader. If for some reason you want to use the legacy data type for your UV Map, take a look here:

[How to apply Geometry Nodes with UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/228241/60486)